# Need Help Diagnosing a Failing P/Invoke Call Only on Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I have the following P/Invoke defined:

```
[DllImport("helper.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl, 
    CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint="F_GetValue")]
private static extern Int32 _F_GetValue(String Formula, ref DATA_STRUCT Data,
    ref DATA_KEY DefaultKeyBuf, ref Double Result);
```

This call succeeds on Windows Vista and later, but fails on Windows XP with this memory exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred 
in helper.dll
```

I tried changing the first two "ref" modifiers to be [In, Out] but that did not solve the problem.

DATA_STRUCT and DATA_KEY are both structs that are instantiated and pre-populated.

Here is the C++ method definition that I am calling:

```
int F_GetValue(const char* pFormula, DATA_STRUCT* pData, 
    DATA_KEY* pDefaultKeyBuf, double* freturn)
```

I'm no P/invoke guru, so don't assume anything.  Is there anything obviously wrong with the way this is defined?  Is there more marshaling to be done (manually)?  I feel like I might be missing something obvious.

EDIT:  as requested, here are the structure definitions in .NET, the C++ F_GetValue() method, and the C++ structure definitions, respectively:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct DATA_STRUCT
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public String DataDir;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public UInt16 LTType;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public UInt16 FOMType;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public UInt16 ResultType;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 136)] // ( POS_BLOCK_SIZE + sizeof(int) + 4 )
    public Byte[] posBlock;
    public DATA_REC dataBuf;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public UInt16 dataLen;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public UInt16 keyNum;
    public DATA_KEY keyBuf;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public UInt16 TNTC;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public Int16 status;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct DATA_KEY
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 17)]
    public String LocName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 17)]
    public String ParName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 13)]
    public String DateTime;
}

int F_GetValue(const char* pFormula, DATA_STRUCT* pData, DATA_KEY* pDefaultKeyBuf, double* freturn)
{

    if (pFormula[0] == 0) // return quickly if nothing to do
    {
        *freturn = blank;
        pData->ResultType = sbit(DATA_BLANK);
        pData->status = B_NO_ERROR;
        return 0;
    }

    if ((_strnicmp(pFormula, "DOTNET_", 7) == 0) || (_strnicmp(pFormula, "(DOTNET_", 7) == 0)) // switch to/from dotnet
    {
        dotnetCalcs = (_strnicmp(pFormula + 7 + ((pFormula[0] == '(') ? 1 : 0), "ON", 2) == 0);
        *freturn = dotnetCalcs ? 1 : 0;
        pData->ResultType = sbit(DATA);
        pData->status = B_NO_ERROR;
        return strlen(pFormula);
    }

    BOOL bComingFromDotNet = (pData->dataLen == 65535);
    if (dotnetCalcs && (!bComingFromDotNet))
    {
        return F_GetValue2(pFormula, pData, pDefaultKeyBuf, freturn);
    }

    if (pSharedMem->bClient && ! bServer)
    {
        if (FromServer(ACTION_OPEN,NULL) == B_NO_ERROR)
        {
            ((CS_FORMULA *)pSharedMem->ClientServer)->nRecords = 1;
            strcpy(((CS_FORMULA *)pSharedMem->ClientServer)->DataDir,pData->DataDir);
            memcpy(&((CS_FORMULA *)pSharedMem->ClientServer)->Formula[0].DefaultKeyBuf,pDefaultKeyBuf,sizeof(DATA_KEY));
            strcpy(((CS_FORMULA *)pSharedMem->ClientServer)->Formula[0].Formula,pFormula);
            ((CS_FORMULA *)pSharedMem->ClientServer)->iType = CSTYPE_FORMULA;
            ((CS_FORMULA *)pSharedMem->ClientServer)->iAction = ACTION_READ;
            if (FromServer(ACTION_READ,NULL) == B_NO_ERROR)
            {
                *freturn = ((CS_FORMULA_RESULT *)pSharedMem->ClientServer)->Data[0].Data;
                pData->ResultType = ((CS_FORMULA_RESULT *)pSharedMem->ClientServer)->Data[0].ResultType;
                pData->status = ((CS_FORMULA_RESULT *)pSharedMem->ClientServer)->Data[0].status;

                FromServer(ACTION_CLOSE,NULL);
                return strlen(pFormula);
            }
            FromServer(ACTION_CLOSE,NULL);
        }
        *freturn = blank;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        BOOL bOpenTemporaryData = bComingFromDotNet || (pData->dataLen == 0);
        if (bOpenTemporaryData)
        {
            DataOpenAndInitialize(pData,NULL);
        }

        int iReturn = F_DoGetValue(pFormula,pData,pDefaultKeyBuf,freturn);

        if (bOpenTemporaryData)
            DataExec(B_CLOSE,pData);

        return iReturn;
    }
}

typedef struct
{
    char DataDir[MAX_PATH];
    unsigned short LTType; 
    unsigned short FOMType; 
    unsigned short ResultType; 
    BTI_BYTE posBlock[POS_BLOCK_SIZE_];
    DATA_REC dataBuf;
    BTI_WORD dataLen;
    BTI_WORD keyNum;
    DATA_KEY keyBuf;
    unsigned short TNTC;
    BTI_SINT status;
} DATA_STRUCT;

typedef struct
{
char    LocName[LP_SIZE];
char    ParName[LP_SIZE];
char    DateTime[13];
} DATA_KEY;
```

For the sake of completeness, I also include this method, F_GetValue2(), which is called in F_GetValue().  And while this looks as though it might be running right back into managed code, it won't.  This method exists for a different purpose, and I cannot assure you that it is not getting called in the case of my XP woes, as it would require that (dotnetCalcs && (!bComingFromDotNet)) be true, which it would not be.

One more thing, the other method that is called in there is F_DoGetValue(), and the set of parameters is then passed on to it.  That method is huge, so I'll not post it here.  But suffice it to say that it parses Formula and uses what it learns to call yet more methods that use the parsed string(s) to fetch data from the database, returning the Double member fReturn back up the chain until it ultimately is delivered back to the C# code via the marshaling.

Comment: We need to see the definitions for DATA_STRUCT and DATA_KEY, both native and managed, and if possible the code for F_GetValue.

Comment: Like Tergiver says, the most likely case is that there's something wrong with your definitions of the structures. The only other thing I'd say to try from the code I can see is *not* marshalling `Formula` as a string but as a character array. Although you've correctly marked the character set as ANSI, so it should work as a string. (Why is the DLL using ANSI strings anyway?)

Comment: Yes, we need the structs. Also, you have not specified the semantics of the interface. Types are never enough. Is the first param in or out? And the last param? Single value. Array?

Comment: @CodyGray The reason they're marked ANSI is because this is very old code.  What you're really looking at is a bridge that was built between legacy C++ code and new .NET code because we could not port it all in a single go.  That C++ code is managing string pointers all over the place, ultimately to provide low-level transactional access to a database.

Comment: You have not added all the C++ code. You are missing the definitions of the array lengths: `POS_BLOCK_SIZE_`, `LP_SIZE`. We are also missing one struct, `DATA_REC`. Also, are you always running 32 bit code? Even on the Vista and later machines? Is it even a p/invoke problem at all? Does the native code run on XP properly. Can you call it from a C++ host?

Comment: Anyway, the way to diagnose this is to strip out everything from the native function and check that it works. Check that all the parameters are received properly. Good old fashioned printing to stdout will suffice. Use `OutputDebugString` if you want to be a bit trendier. Then add back the code bit by bit. Until you find the point of failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the problem turned out to be quite different from what evidence suggested (especially given my level of knowledge regarding P/Invoke).  In fact, the problem was the result of using this declaration:

```
__declspec( thread ) BOOL dotnetCalcs = FALSE;
```

After stepping into the code, I found that it failed on this line:

```
if (dotnetCalcs && (!bComingFromDotNet))
```

The member "dotnetCalcs" is declared as thread local storage, and after doing some research, it appears that it is a known fail on XP.  One example clue I found was the comment at the end of this MSDN page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w1sdazb(v=vs.80).aspx

The part about delayed load is applicable in this instance, as the DLL in question is being loaded due to the DllImport.

Thank you to all who responded, and I'm sorry for having led a goose chase.  But in the end, the trouble of setting up a special debug station proved worth the effort.

The fix:

Replacing the __declspec(thread) approach with calls to TLS methods.  At DllMain() I establish a TLS index and hold it globally, setting the initial value with TlsSetValue().  All subsequent requesters are then using that index to retrieve the TLS value with TlsGetValue().  Whenever the value changes, just use TlsGetValue() again to set the value.  Always remember to cast with LPVOID as that is the type these use.

Comment: As I suspected. Not anything to do with pinvoke at all!

Answer (score 2):

```
   [StructLayout(..., Pack = 1)]
```

There is no #pragma pack visible in the C code, odds that the structure packing in your native code is actually 1 are low.  The default is 8, same default for [StructLayout].  A minimum sanity check is that Marshal.SizeOf() on your structure types in C# returns the exact same value as sizeof() in your C code.  It will not work correctly when there's a mismatch and a random AV is indeed likely.

And use the debugger to diagnose the AV.  Project + Properties, Debug tab, tick the unmanaged code debugging option so you can debug both your C# and your C code.  Set a breakpoint on first statement in the C function.  And check that the debug view of the passed structure pointers matches the data you assigned in your C# code.  Trouble is usually located near the end of the structure.  Debug + Exceptions, tick the thrown box for Win32 exceptions to let the debugger stop when the AV exception occurs.

Comment: There is, it appears at the head of the same code page in which the C++ structures are defined:  #pragma pack(1).  I am going to try and setup a debugger to inspect what's happening when it crosses over.  I didn't have such a setup before, and honestly, had hoped to avoid doing so by asking here first.  Clearly, it's unavoidable though, so on I go!

Comment: I have noticed thus far that the passed in structures arrive garbled.  To what degree I am not yet sure.  But even that begs an obvious question:  why does this only happen on XP?  Is there some inherent difference in the marshaling?  They're shown in debug as "<Bad Ptr>", so I don't know what's really happening, but since this all works just fine when run on Windows 7...

Comment: No, the pinvoke marshaller doesn't care that it is running on XP.  Good odds that it just doesn't work properly on Win7 either, you just didn't get slapped with an AV yet.  There is no guarantee that you'll get one.